# How do i properly compare dates in moment.js using node.js + mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, momentjs

I have two dates that I would like to compare , current date and future date

in my mongodb database (I'm using mongoose as its ORM)

```
var User = mongoose.Schema({
    future_month: String
});
```

This is futureMonth value

```
future_month = moment().add(1, 'M').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

and I tried to compare the current date and future date

```
exports.isTrue = function() {
    var currentDate = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY");
    if (currentDate <= req.user.future_month) {
       console.log("Still Active");
    } else {
       console.log("You have to pay");
    }
}
```

I always get `"You have to pay"` even though

```
currentDate = 31-10-2015
req.user.future_month = 30/11/2015
```

It is supposed to run `"Still Active"` because `currentDate` is less than `req.user.future_month` value

and one more thing the typeof `currentDate` and `future_month` are both strings, that's why I put mongoose field as a string type. Just to let you guys know.

Comment: have you noticed the format of two date strings?`31-10-2015` and `30/11/2015`

Comment: Using strings for storing dates and comparing them is a very bad idea. The issue here is simple: '31' is superior to '30' when you compare strings so your `currentDate` is "after" your `future_month`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare strings.  That won't work in most cases, especially with the format you're using.  Instead, compare `moment` objects, and use the built-in functions rather than comparison operators.

```
// get the start of the current date, as a moment object
var today = moment().startOf('day');

// parse the input string to a moment object using the format that matches
var future = moment(req.user.future_month, "DD/MM/YYYY");

// use the isAfter function to compare
if (future.isAfter(today)) {
    ...
```

Note that I used `isAfter` function and flipped the sides of the comparison because you had `today <= future`, and moment only has `isAfter` and `isBefore`.  If instead you had `today < future`, then I'd written it as `today.isBefore(future)` instead.

Also note that the `startOf('day')` will usually be midnight, but not always, due to time zones and DST. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for a great answer, but jut wondering is possible to use, moment().toDate() instead of moment().startOf('day')

Comment: `toDate` gives you a `Date` object for the equivalent date and time.  Remember, `Date` is misnamed, it is always a date and time.  `startOf('day')` keeps it as a `moment` object and shifts the time to the beginning of the day.